# where did the concrete splitting test calculated stress formulat come from?

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, applied-mechanics, stresses, concrete

In compression test of cylindrical concrete sample we get the normal stress easily by dividing failure force by sample cross section, but how we can explain the formulat used to determine tensile stress in splitting tensile test?: F<sub>st</sub>=2P/(πDLB)
[image: splitting test]
[image: tensile test formula]

Comment: Your source for this?

Comment: european and american (ASTM C 496) splitting tensile test standards

Comment: Then you should provide the reference so it is not plagiarism.

Comment: The theoretical basis for computing the tensile strength of a split cylinder test has been derived from the theory of linear elasticity (Timoshenko, 1934: pp.104-108).